# How can I store data from an array into the mySQL database?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to store data from an array into my database.

This is how my Array looks when I do  `print_r($animals);`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [animal] => Cat
            [name] => Tom
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [animal] => Dog
            [name] => Bob
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [animal] => Bird
            [name] => Sam
        )
    [3] => ....
```

This is how I try to store the data, but for some reason it doesn't work, nothing is stored:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO animals (animal,name) values(?,?) ";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($animals as $row) {
   $q->execute(array(
      $row['animal'],
      $row['name'],));
}
Database::disconnect();
```

If I write the following for example the storing works, but only the first entry is stored (Cat and Tom)

```
foreach($animals as $row) {             
    $name = $row['name'];
    $animal = $row['animal'];
}

$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO animals (animal,name) values(?,?) ";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($animal,$name));
Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: Your table may be transactional and you may need to commit, i.e $pdo->commit();

Comment: Sorry is `print_r($animals);` what is in `$properties`?

Comment: Also you are not checking the status of any of these database access commands. How will you know whats wrong if you dont look????

Comment: Could it be that you just have a comma too much: `$row['name'],));`

Comment: Sorry, `$properties` was wrong, it should be `$animals`, I updated the mistake

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I deleted the comma, now it works, but it is still storing only one column (only cat and Tom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt made more sense. Remember you only need to `prepare` a parameterised statement once, then you can run it 1000 times if you like as long as you replace the parametes each time.

Also as you are setting PDO to emit Exceptions on error you should code this in a Try/Catch block

```
    try {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO animals (animal,name) values(?,?) ";

        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        foreach($animals as $row) {

            $q->execute(array($row['animal'], $row['name']));
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        echo $pe->getMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: unfortunately I get a white page, if I use the code

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the page is not white, but there will be nothing stored in the database

Comment: Ok, I found the mistake. Now it works, but with your code there is also only  one entry in the database (only Cat and Tom)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84804/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-jarla).

Comment: Hello, sorry, I was not on my desktop, are you still in the chat?

Comment: this is my printr result: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [animal] => Cat [name] => Tom ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [animal] => Dog [name] => Bob ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [animal] => Bird [name] => Sam ) )`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code like this, it will work.

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
foreach($animals as $row) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO animals (animal,name) values($row['animal'], $row['name']) ";
   $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute();
}
Database::disconnect();
```

I can't explain it well, but I know the CodeIgniter Framework used PDO this way for SQL execution.

Answer (score 0):

The first one you got syntax error extra comma:

```
foreach($animals as $row) {
   $q->execute(array(
      $row['animal'],
      $row['name'],));//extra comma
}
```

The second one you got the loop at the top overwriting the variables. This means it will insert the last row.

So remove the comma in that for each or use for loop:

```
for($i=0; $i< count($animals); $i++) {
   $q->execute(array(
      $animals[$i]['animal'],
      $animals[$i]['name']));
}
```